# Facebook open graph og:image viewed by facebook but not displayed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have read quite a number of SO post on the topic however my problem still persists : Facebook sees my meta tags as raw tag found but does not display or include image during the open graph display. This is the Url i am trying to post on facebook :

https://holyunions.com/govt-releases-gh-cent-465-million-for-start-of-one-district-one-factory-project-general-language-en-article-118

And This is my output of my code

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Govt releases GH¢465 million for start of one-district-one factory project - General :. Twum Barimah" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://holyunions.com/govt-releases-gh-cent-465-million-for-start-of-one-district-one-factory-project-general-language-en-article-118" />
<meta property="og:description" content=""/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="532235306919626"/>

<meta property="og:image" content="http://holyunions.com/js/max_john_richeditor/lib/tiny_mce/plugins/openmanager/uploads/images/image_11_04_2017_12_24_02_1491913442-42.png" /> 
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://holyunions.com/js/max_john_richeditor/lib/tiny_mce/plugins/openmanager/uploads/images/image_11_04_2017_12_24_02_1491913442-42.png" />  
<meta property="og:image:width" content="500" />  
<meta property="og:image:height" content="285" />  
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Holy Unions : Home of Marriages" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100004005747278"/>
```

[image]

The og image properties are well defined however [Facebook after displaying them as tags](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/), still does not fetch the image neither does it display the image nor the description in the open graph properties. 
[image]

**How do I display the image that facebook sees as url ?**

Comment: Looks fine to me (or solved by now?) - when I share it on Facebook, the image is used as specified.

Comment: Here it is not and any other link i use still does not display the image. It shows the box in which the image should be but it does not show the image